# What is the size of char[]?

Tags: java, char, size

I'm making hash algorithm, the block of message is 512 bits. 
In `C/C++` I can store in `char[64]`, but `Java` `char` takes 2 bytes.

Question: 512 bits of information are `char[32]` or `char[64]`?

Comment: You could use byte[64] then

Answer (score 6):

Char is 16bit in Java. So char[32] should be enough for 512bits. 
I think using byte[64] is better though because everyone know a byte is 8 bits and char[32] makes the code harder to read. Also you don't store characters but bits.

Comment: Because as you can see not everyone knows the size of a char ;) and my guess is everyone knows that a byte is 8 bits. Also the message needed to be stored is 512 bits and not characters.

Comment: Not harder, need to do bitwise manipulations like shifting first 8 to left, assign the second one etc

Comment: But if I should manipulate with message and sbox[] (e.g. substitution) and symbols of sbox are too much and I can't store sbox as Byte or Char?

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html):

> **char**: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff'
>   (or 65,535 inclusive).

So in order to store 512 bits, you should have an array of size 32.

Answer (score 1):

Why use a `char[]`?

A hash value consists of `byte`s so the logical choice would be to use a `byte[64]`.

The datatype `char` is intended to be used as a character and not as a number.